# Detect dead pixel on android phone screen

Tags: android, screen, pixel

I want to write a piece of code that checks the android phone/tablet screen for dead pixels.

I have seen programs on google play that can do it but couldn't find a lead on how to write a similar program.

Any help would mean a lot.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All the apps I've seen on the Play store that do this simply show a single color screen, and ask the user to manually check to see if any pixels are a different color.

There are no API's that allow you to find dead pixels - after all Android believes that is has asked the display to show a certain color at that point, and it cannot tell that the hardware is actually showing something different.  (The screenshot routines, only usable in certain limited circumstances, will likewise not show dead pixels - they show the color that should be there).

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to programmatically detect a dead pixel...scripts can detect whether the display is working or not working completely but dead pixel is basically a partially working display which is impossible to detect. But as @zmarties mentioned there are a number of [black screen app](https://darkblackscreen.com) that can go completely full screen and change color repeatedly. Then you need to look closely for any dead or stuck pixels.